# Copy data from one table to another in diffrent databases

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

I'm having a using sql 5.5 version. I'm having a table called 'item' in 'catering' database. And with few changes in ER diagram I modified that database to 'cateringnew'. So in that db there is a table called 'item'. But there is no data in it. 
I used this cord to copy old item data to new. But it is not working.. I'm using mysql query browser.

```
USE cateringnew
 GO

 INSERT INTO dbo.cateringnew(itid, itname, bprice, sprice, avqty, scaid)
 SELECT itid, itname, bprice, sprice, avqty, scaid
 FROM catering.dbo.item
```

But nothing output, not even a error. Please help me.

Comment: does this return anything? `USE cateringnew
 GO 
 SELECT itid, itname, bprice, sprice, avqty, scaid
 FROM catering.dbo.item`

Comment: @saUce no nothing. :( I tried execute in new tab too. but no output.

Comment: Does `USE catering GO SELECT itid, itname, bprice, sprice, avqty, scaid FROM dbo.item` this return anything?

Comment: in this case you need to figure what happened to the data in original table. Nothing we can do here.

Comment: @sauce you mean that when I'm modifying ER using my old database and when I'm making making new db it should copy all the data? are you sure.. I changed lots of relationships in that ER diagram. But not this table's any relation.

Comment: It is not going to copy data automatically, but it is possible when you were changing your old database you truncated the table. If nothing is returned in select statement there is nothing that anyone would be able to help you with. If you got some error back than there is possibility for an answer.

Comment: :( ok. how can I make my modified ER diagram to copy data automaticly

Comment: Modifying ER diagram and copying data is two separate function. In [tag:sql-server] you can user `SELECT * INTO MyNewTable FROM MyOldTable` this will create new table and copy data at same time. Not sure if it works in [tag:MySQL]

Comment: but I have two databases.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer myself. :) Thanks for your effort guys.

```
 INSERT INTO cateringnew.item (itname,bprice,sprice,avqty,scaid)
 SELECT item.itname,item.bprice,item.sprice,item.avqty,item.scaid
 FROM catering.item;
```